# How to be sure if "DataTables" Jquery Plugin initialised correctly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have many DataTables-Objects in a Form.
How to can i check if all of them initialised correctly?
I need that because I use Ajax to submit the form.

Comment: Try submitting the form..?

Comment: What you mean with "try submitting the form"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation: http://datatables.net/api

> fnIsDataTable
>
> Check if a TABLE node is a DataTable table already or not.

To gather all uninitialized datatables:

```
var uninitialized = $('.should_be_datatable').filter(function() {
    return !$.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable(this);
});
```

To test if there exist any that are not initialized yet:

```
if (uninitialized.length) {
    // Some datatables have not been initialized!
}
```

To initialize the uninitialized datatables:

```
uninitialized.each(function() {
    $(this).dataTable();
});
```