# How to check if variable is an initialized DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there a way to determine if a variable is an initialized DataTable or not? I'm basically trying to do this:

```
if (isDataTable(variable)) {
    // datatable ... do datatable stuff
} else {
    // not a datatable... do other stuff
}
```

I assumed [`$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()) could be used, but this only works for table selectors, not for variables containing an initialized DataTable. <strike>This function is returning false for such variables</strike> (**EDIT:** the creator of DataTables has since extended `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()` in [this commit](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/commit/0a26b7c6dd2a53ae40ade77d75fb2795890233f3) so that this is no longer true):

```
var table = $("#table").DataTable(); // Valid initialized DataTable
console.log($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#table")); // Returns true
console.log($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(table)); // Returns false...why?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I [asked this question](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38053/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-initialized-datatable) to the creator of DataTables, and he suggested **using `instanceof`**:

```
if (table instanceof $.fn.dataTable.Api) {
    // variable "table" is a valid initialized DataTable ... do datatable stuff
} else {
    // variable "table" is not a datatable... do other stuff
}
```

**This approach works exactly as needed**. He also went on to extend `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()` in [this commit](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/commit/0a26b7c6dd2a53ae40ade77d75fb2795890233f3) so that it will allow variable inputs.

Comment: Note you can only call `$("#my_table_id").DataTable()` if it's already been initialized -- if you call prior to initialization, you will get an exception thrown: `jquery.dataTables.js:5887 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'aDataSort')`. This will also have the side-effect of "initializing" the table to be empty, such that if you try to later (legitimately) initialize the DataTable without first destroying what you just made, you will get another browser error saying a DataTable can only be initialized once.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with calling `.DataTable()` on an uninitialized DataTable element. The line `var table = $("#table").DataTable()` is purely for an example demonstrating that `instanceof` will return true for such.

Comment: No. The first sentence of your question reads: "Is there a way to determine if a variable is an initialized DataTable or not?" In order to answer that question, we must necessarily test against an uninitialized DataTable as well as an initialized one. The first line of code from your original answer (now edited) was _misleading_ as it would return a DataTable (if one was initialized) or attempt to create it if not (throwing a browser error due to invalid constructor arguments).

Comment: At that point, the table would be initialized no matter what. Thus your following line only tests against an initialized table, and never against an uninitialized one. With your answer, it was impossible to ever trigger the "else" branch. The "table" id in your current answer could never be obtained without error unless the table was already initialized in the first place, which is a tautology.

Comment: The first line of code was *supposed* to be an initialized DataTable because I was showing that `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()` returned false for *variables containing an initialized DataTable*. Did you see the comment `// Returns false...why?` I have edited the question to make that clearer for you.

Comment: You still don't understand what the problem is with both the question and the answer. `// Returns false...why?` is in reference to the _safe_ way of testing this (which at the time of the question, returned false, but now would return true). The problem is the `table` variable in the question. You could not set up a valid test this way if the DataTable was not initialized, as it would throw an error. Instead, if you set up the variable as `var table = $("#table")` and test using the `isDataTable`, function you will get expected answer. Not so with the `instanceof` approach. Hence, misleading.

Comment: This code not working for me as of 2024 February. I used the following method.
$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(`#${dataTable.attr('id')}`)

Comment: @LakshithaKanchana yes you're right, I added a note about that method at the bottom of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass an JQuery instance to `isDataTable()`.

`isDataTable()` requires an ID.

For more information : [isDataTable()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable%28%29)

Please check this:

[How to check if DataTables are initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919790/how-to-be-sure-if-datatables-jquery-plugin-initialised-correctly)

Comment: I understand how to use `isDataTable()`. My question is how can a variable be checked if it is an initialized DataTable or not?

Comment: I have just answered this question : > Why does this function return false? I will improve my answer.

Comment: Why I can not use isDataTable? I have jTable version 2.4. For me, it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**1. If you want to check by the id of the data table follow:**

```
$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#id_of_my_data_table');
```

**2. If you want to check with a jQuery object follow this method:**

**method I:**

```
dataTable instanceof $.fn.dataTable.Api
```

**method II:**

```
$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#' + dataTable.attr('id'));
```

Any other method is in above answers not working for me as of 2024-Feb. No idea why.

Comment: It appears that [Allan has deployed the latest version of DataTables (2.0.0) last week](https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.0/). Perhaps that has something to do with it?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was actually my fault!!. Had something to do with pass by reference and pass by value. I corrected by answer by adding all 3 methods.

Answer (score -1):

From Documentacion of DataTable:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()

> This method provides the ability to check if a ***table (tag)*** node is already a
>   DataTable or not. This can be useful to ensure that you don't
>   re-initialise a table that is already a DataTable.

Comment: I've already provided that link in my question. Is there a way to check if a variable is an initialized DataTable?

Comment: This answer is now outdated, I spoke with Allan and he has modified `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()` to accept variable input.

Comment: Where is $.fn.dataTable defined? For me, I have jTable 2.4 it is not in the source file.

Answer (score -1):

The issue with the accepted answer is that it will prove difficult to get a proper reference to the actual DataTable element without having initialized the DataTable in the first place.

Instead, the newer versions of DataTables lets you flexibly use the `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable` function reliably.

Before initialization:

```
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#my_table")
false
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable($("#my_table"))
false
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable($("#my_table").eq(0))
false
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable($("#my_table").get(0))
false
```

After initialization:

```
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#my_table")
true
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable($("#my_table"))
true
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable($("#my_table").eq(0))
true
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable($("#my_table").get(0))
true
```

Comment: your answer here is incorrect and misleading. `table instanceof $.fn.dataTable.Api` does not cause any browser error, and my answer already references the newer `isDataTable()` function. I'm the reason why Alan refactored that function in the first place.

Comment: the problem is not my answer, but with you mindlessly copying and pasting code from StackOverflow.

Comment: With your kind of wild assumptions, it's no wonder your answer was poorly written.

Comment: Not wild assumptions, but common sense. Irritable people like you make SO a bad experience.

Comment: Look in the mirror, bub. Your "common sense" is wrong.